# How to find dates in a csv file using a regular expression and store in an array [using Ruby]?

Tags: ruby, regex, arrays, csv

I have data stored in a csv file that looks like this:

```
Date,BLOCK,,Wood,Miscellaneous,,Totals,MO
Saturday,4055-RU,4055-AR,4091,1139,1158,,100
11/13/15,C Sort,B,C,iGPS,PECO,,
Starting,758,"3,936",840,0,0,"5,534",
Sorted,656,736,540,162,64,"2,158",
Subtotal 1,"1,414","4,672","1,380",162,64,"7,692",
Shipped,0,"1,152",620,162,64,"1,898",
,"1,414","3,520",860,0,0,"5,794",
Physical,"1,414","3,520",860,0,0,"5,794",
Variance,0,0,0,0,0,0,

Date,BLOCK,,Wood,Miscellaneous,,Totals,MO
Saturday,4055-RU,4055-AR,4091,1139,1158,,100
11/14/15,C Sort,B,C,iGPS,PECO,,
Starting,758,"3,936",840,0,0,"5,534",
Sorted,656,736,540,162,64,"2,158",
Subtotal 1,"1,414","4,672","1,380",162,64,"7,692"
Shipped,0,"1,152",620,162,64,"1,898"
,"1,414","3,520",860,0,0,"5,794"
Physical,"1,414","3,520",860,0,0,"5,794"
Variance,0,0,0,0,0,0
```

and I need to make an array of all the dates mentioned (in this case, dates = ['11/13/15', '11/14/15'].

I believe it is possible to pull this info out using a regular expression, but I don't really understand how they work/how to go about this. So, how can I extract the dates?

EDIT: I can sort through the data by row using CSV.foreach, but the trouble I am having is to tell the program to pull out anything that matches a date format (ie. 11/13/15). Does that make more sense of my question?

Thank you!
 - Sean

Comment: I think it is a lot easier to use a existing CSV parser for this than to use a complex, unreadable and a incomplete regular expression. I don't work in Ruby but I am sure there will be a lot of existing CSV parsers which do this job well. Looks like there is a CSV module which ships with Ruby, may be you can use that. http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html

Comment: Ruby has a CSV parser. If it doesn't, I'll be ashamed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct one liner is:

```
File.open('yourfile.csv').read.scan /\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{2}/
```

and by the way \d{2} is so much nicer than \d\d and here's why:

- you can see the 2. \d{2} reads like "2 digit number" (once you're
  used to it)
- if you want to change it to 1 or 2 digits you can do {1,2}

Comment: This is much easier to read. Out of curiosity, why use File.open instead of CSV.open?

Comment: File.read puts the entire contents into a string. CSV builds arrays.

Answer (score 0):

You could get a first approximation with this:

```
dates = CSV.open('x.csv').map{|r| r.select { |x| x =~ /\d\d\/\d\d\/\d\d/ } }.flatten
```

and then, if needed, scan through the elements of `dates` to make sure numbers are in the proper ranges (so that you don't accidentally include a date that claims to be Feb 31 2001). If you want to check the format, you could use [`DateTime.strptime`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/date/rdoc/DateTime.html#method-c-strptime) and catch ArgumentErrors:

```
clean = dates.select do |d|
    begin
        # I'm guessing on the date format.
        DateTime.strptime(d, '%m/%d/%y')
    rescue ArgumentError
        nil
    end
end
```

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted but couldn't figure out! Thanks!

Comment: sorry mu, I didn't mean to imply that you were incorrect, just that it could be more concise.

Answer (score 0):

```
dates = []
File.open('yourfile.csv').each_line do |line|
  if m = line.match(/^\d\d\/\d\d\/\d\d/)
    dates.push m 
  end
end

puts dates
```

BTW. I am sure someone could write this as a one-liner, but this might be a little easier to understand for someone new to Ruby.

I making these assumptions:

- All dates are of the format mm/dd/yy.
- All dates that you want in the array are at the start of each line.
- You don't need to verify that it is a valid date.

Comment: Ah, someone already did write it as one line before I could even finish typing the answer.